# What is the cause of Android Studio's emulator being slow to save state?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My Android Studio emulator is very slow to turn off.

When I try to shut down the emulator, I am always greeted with a dialog box stating

> Do you want to save the current state for the next quick boot?Note:
>   Recent saves seem to have been slow.

My emulator configuration is the following

- Device: Pixel 2 XL API P
- RAM: 6144 MB
- VM Heap: 256 MB
- Internal Storage: 4096 MB
- SD Card: 100 MB

What could be the cause of the slow emulator shut down?

Comment: I assume it is the huge RAM. What happens is the whole RAM is saved to the hard drive and 6 GB is a lot of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was the large amount of allocated RAM, as noted by Uriel Frankel. I halved the amount of RAM to 3 GB and the warning went away.